# Using multiple ='s for IN?

Tags: mysql, sql

What would be the difference between doing:

```
SELECT person FROM population WHERE id = 1 or id = 2 or id = 3
```

and -

```
SELECT person FROM population WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Are they executed the exact same way? What difference is there? Would there ever be a reason where one would you `IN` rather than multiple `=`'s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they perform the same thing. The `IN` minimizes the query string. *That's all.* Such statements help in query optimization.

One difference in these two comparison operators would be that `IN` uses a `SET` of values to compare, unlike the "=" or "<>" which takes a single value.

---

According to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

> if *expr* is equal to any of the values in the IN list, else returns 0.
>   If all values are constants, they are evaluated according to the type
>   of *expr* and sorted. The search for the item then is done using a
>   binary search. This means **IN is very quick** if the IN value list
>   consists entirely of constants.